# How to extract subtitles from a .mkv file using GStreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

If `gst-discover-1.0` verified a .mkv has subtitles, then how to extract the subtitles with `gst-launch-1.0`? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of subtitles? You'll have to get the caps from gst-discoverer-1.0 and then do something like

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/path/to/mkv ! matroskademux ! "text/x-raw" ! filesink location=subtitles
```

where "text/x-raw" is replaced by the caps of the subtitle stream. Alternatively you can also specify the link by pad name

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/path/to/mkv ! matroskademux name=demux   demux.subtitle_%u ! filesink location=subtitles
```

where %u should be the track number of the subtitle stream.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question. The subtitle I extracted doesn't have timestamp. How to fix it? Is it possible to specify the format of the subtitle file that we want to output, such as in .srt format? Thanks, really really appreciate it. Have a nice day.

Comment: The Matroska file you used apparently contains plain text subtitles, with the timestamps being stored in the Matroska container itself instead of the subtitle stream. You could use the srtenc element for encoding those into SRT for example.

Comment: According to gst-discoverer-1.0, the MIME-type of the subtitle is application/x-ass. Could you please give me a hint or an example of how to convert it to a .srt file? I'm new to GStreamer. In fact, I was reading http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Tutorials and finished only the first 5 basic tutorials. Thanks. Really appreciate. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Use ssaparse and then srtenc. You'll lose most of the formatting of ASS then though.

Comment: It works. Thank you, Mr. Dröge. Thank you so much. Really really appreciate your help. I got stuck in this problem for a year now. Have tried libvlc, but in vain, and then go back to GStreamer. Finally... Thank you, really.

Comment: Hello. How to do the same, if i want to do it in my app (c++) in steps? It is not really clear for me. Have something, but it is not working or not linking. I mean in code lines: GstElement* result = gst_pipeline_new("VideoPlayback"); GstElement* reader = gst_element_factory_make(filesrc, "fileReader");....gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(result),.....); gst_element_link(reader, _demuxer);....